# Codeigniter - A PHP Error was encountered Undefined variable: home_post

Tags: php, codeigniter

so i wanna load image from database using codeigniter. here's my code:

**Controller: Pweb**

```
    public function display($id=FALSE)
    {
        if ($id==FALSE){
        $data["home_post"] = $this->M_pweb->displays();
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('upload', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');

        }else{
            $data["post"] = $this->M_pweb->displays($id);
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('upload', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
        }
    }
```

**Models: M_pweb**

```
    public function displays($id=FALSE)
    {
        if ($id==FALSE){
            return $this->db->get("post")->result_array();

        }else{
            $query = $this->db->get_where("post", array('id'=>$id));
            return $query->row();
        }
        
    }
```

**Views: upload**

```
    <ul class="collection">
    <?php foreach ($home_post as $data ): ?>
    <li class="collection-item avatar">
        <img src="<?=site_url("upload/post/".$data["filename"]) ?>" class="circle">
        <p class="title"><?= $data["name"];?></p>
        <small><?= $data["description"];?></small>
        <a href="<?= site_url("pweb/upload/".$data["id"]) ?>" class="secondary-content">
            <i class="material-icons">visibility</i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
```

It give error like this:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: home_post
>
> Filename: views/upload.php
>
> Line Number: 47
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\pweb\application\views\upload.php Line: 47
>
> Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\pweb\application\controllers\Pweb.php Line: 117
>
> Function: view

and

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>
> Filename: views/upload.php
>
> Line Number: 47
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\pweb\application\views\upload.php Line: 47
>
> Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\pweb\application\controllers\Pweb.php Line: 117
>
> Function: view

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your controller with the below code:
( In your HTML code, foreach loop uses the "home_post" variable which is not defined in the else condition of your controller.

**Controller: Pweb**

```
public function display($id=FALSE)
{
    if ($id==FALSE){
    $data["home_post"] = $this->M_pweb->displays();
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('upload', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer');

    }else{
        $data["home_post"] = $this->M_pweb->displays($id);
                  ^
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('upload', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it has no change and still error. i'm curious why i can't read data with this algorithm

Comment: @initialha please update your question with updated code so we will figure out where the issue is. Thanks